# Load a foreign activity into own view?

Tags: android

I'm trying to load the main activity of another app into my own view hierarchy, similar to what can be done with "Fragments".

I've tried:

```
Context foreignContext = createPackageContext("com.android.calculator2", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY | Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
Class<?> foreignClass = foreignContext.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, foreignClass);

View view = getLocalActivityManager()
          .startActivity("ReferenceName", intent
          .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
          .getDecorView();
          this.setContentView(view);
```

This fails with a `ClassNotFoundException` as it tries to find `com.my.app/com.android.calculator2.Calculator` (I assume the `Local` in `getLocalActivityManager` adds the prefix?)

Is there any way to achieve this? I don't need to interact with the foreign activity or its code, just display it within my own activity, so simply launching it with an intent wouldn't work. I thought this wasn't possible due to security considerations, but if I can (theoretically) access the foreign app's code, it should be possible to somehow run its `onCreate` method?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice, then I could have 50 of the top selling apps on the market in just a few minutes! ;-)  I think this falls under the category of injection, or I guess inverse injection and I doubt you can do this without some serious hacking and as yet undiscovered and serious security holes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve this?

Absolutely not. For starters, it would be a serious security violation.

> if I can (theoretically) access the foreign app's code, it should be possible to somehow run its onCreate method?

You can't access the foreign app's code. And, their activity is not in your manifest.

Answer (score 2):

the only thin i know, is to use the manifest setting: sharedUserId

but this will only work if you know the foreign key

> android:sharedUserId
>
> The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared with other applications. By default, Android assigns each application its own unique user ID. However, if this attribute is set to the same value for two or more applications, they will all share the same ID — provided that they are also signed by the same certificate. Application with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if desired, run in the same process.